# In angular 2 I have 2 parent components that need to emit and listen but my codes not working

Tags: angular

In angular 2 I have 2 parent components that need to emit and listen but my codes not working

I basically have a parent component that needs to do a broadcast to another parent component so that that component can update itself.

**This is my component emitting:**

```
  @Output() userUpdated = new EventEmitter();

  userUpdated = "userUpdated($event)";

  userUpdated.emit("test");
```

**This is my other parent component listening for the emit:**

```
  userUpdated(item) {
    this.getAllUnReadMessages();
  }
```

Outcome is a lot of console errors.

> I tried to follow this: http://learnangular2.com/outputs/

But the problem is they want me to pay the emit into the component which I cannot do for this scenario.

I just need to do a basic emit or broadcast to another component.
Its becoming difficult for something simple.

I've only ever go this working for parent to child components.

But I now need it to work for parent to parent.

Comment: please show the component template

Comment: @quindimildev there is nothing to show in the template, its just text

Comment: @quindimildev - the error i get is "userUpdated is not defined"

Comment: In the template is where you bind the event from one component to other. It is well explained in the tutorial you are following

Comment: @quindimildev I know and I have got it working like that for some of my other code. But for this example I need 2 parent components to communicate

Comment: Check this https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html#!#bidirectional-service

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK here's the plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/qMnXG7oxF3SdTptKHUen?p=preview

There are lots of answers to this question on stackoverflow and you are posting this question for not the first time..

You will first make a shared service for your app

```
import {Subject} from 'rxjs/Subject';

@Injectable()
export class MyService {

    public invokeEvent:Subject<any> = new Subject();

    constructor() {}
}
```

then provide it in your module so that components will share the same instance of this component (singleton)

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [ BrowserModule ],
  providers: [MyService]
  declarations: [ App, AnotherApp ],
  bootstrap: [ App ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

From this point on it's all about the usage of `Subject` in your components.

If you want to emit an event, call it with `next`

```
this._myService.invokeEvent.next(this.counter++);
```

and to receive/listen, just subscribe:

```
this._myService.invokeEvent.subscribe((value) => {
           console.log(value); 
           this.name = value;
         });
```

Comment: seems too much for something so simple. In angular 1 i would just broadcast and then have a listener. I dont want to make a new service.

Comment: I've tried your code. I'm getting an error: Subject is not defined

Comment: @AngularM did you import subject?

Comment: Now that it works, it doesnt seem to update the view? it emits to the other componenet but it doesnt update the view

Comment: @AngularM well your question is very generic as you can appreciate. I don't know your setup or any other thing. As you can see in the plunker it is updating the view. Make another question and be specific about the situation.

Comment: ignore that its working now - it was my code. thought i had to do something similar to $apply()