# Angular 2 - Communication between components

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular2-template

I have the following scenario:

```
<router-outlet name="sidebar"></router-outlet>

<div class="content-wrapper">    
      <router-outlet name="header"></router-outlet>

      <div class="content">
          <router-outlet></router-outlet>
      </div>
</div>
```

Page content will be loaded in router-outlet. But page title and its breadcrumb path exists in router-outlet "header".

I know the page content components can't communicate with header components.

What would you suggest me so I could fill Title and Breadcrumb information according to active component in the generic router outlet?

Thanks very much!

Comment: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html

Comment: Thanks for replying me. I've seen this guide before, but it doesn't reply my question since components are on different routers.

Comment: IMO I think bidirectional-service will be the way to go for this use case.

Comment: @KrisHollenbeck But components don't have parent-child relationship. They're siblings in different routers.

Comment: If they are all apart of the same app you should be able to share info between them via a service. The service would hold the information that needs to be sent back and forth between components that have no direct relationship. For example if you inject a service in your top level `ngModule` you will have access to that service globally across your application.

Comment: Use a shared service

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40535194/in-angular-2-i-have-2-parent-components-that-need-to-emit-and-listen-but-my-code/40535422#40535422