# How to publish event not in component angular 2?

Tags: events, angular, arguments

How to publish event not in component of angular 2?
I try:

```
let events = new Events(//Need agruments here);
events.publish('myevent');
```

But that need to pass in class arguments. How to do this?
I want global event catch in component. And event to publish anythere.

Explain:
I have component where I want to catch event.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'category-blocks-listproductspage',
  templateUrl: '/mobilesiteapp/template/?path=pages/category/blocks/listproductspage'
})

export class CatalogBlocksListProductsPage extends AbstractBlock{
  constructor(
    public events: Events
  ){
    this.events.subscribe('category-blocks-filterspage.apply', (eventsData) => {
      this.applyFilters(eventsData[0]);
    });
  }
}
```

And I have class where I want to publish Event.

```
export class ProductItem{
   updateFavorite(response: Object, data: any)
  {
    this.product.toggleInFavorite(response, data);
    let events = new Events(//Need agruments here);
    events.publish('favorite-block-favoritepage.refresh', response['response']);
  }
}
```

How to do this? Sorry for bad English.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In angular 2 I have 2 parent components that need to emit and listen but my codes not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40535194/in-angular-2-i-have-2-parent-components-that-need-to-emit-and-listen-but-my-code)

Comment: No. It is not the same.

Comment: Please improve your question. What is `Events`. What is the expected behavior? What have you tried, where did you fail?

Comment: Improved. Look up, please.

Comment: I still can't find information about what `Events` is supposed to be.